# Uploading app to Web App Engine in IntelliJ

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I'm trying to deploy my app to Web App Engine. I have WAE module in web part of my project; there is a path specified in **Modules/web/Google App Engine**:

```
 /Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.12/
```

Although when I click on we in general (**Modules/web/"Paths"** tab), I see following settings:

```
Output path:
/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/NameOfMyProject/web/target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
```

### **The problem is:**

When I click "Upload Web App Engine Application" following error appears:

```
 Bad configuration: Could not locate 
 /Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/NameOfMyProject/web/target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

I don't get it why it tries to search in wrong directory, not the one specified in Modules. Please advise.

### **Edit**

I noticed that in **Modules/web/"Sources"** tab whole folder named "target" is excluded. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message

```
Bad configuration: Could not locate 
/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/NameOfMyProject/web/target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

, the deployment code is looking for [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig), a crucial config file for your App Engine app. It's looking for that file here:

`/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/NameOfMyProject/web/target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml`

Is it possible that the file

`/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/NameOfMyProject/web/target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml`

could not be located ("`Bad configuration: Could not locate "`) because the file

`/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/NameOfMyProject/web/target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml`

does not exist?

---

The path `/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.12/` is the path to your [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit), not the target folder, and is not related to this issue.

The target file is excluded from "sources" because "sources" is the location of files that are included as source code into the build. The `target` folder is the opposite of source files - it's the flattened-out [WAR archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28file_format%29) that is used to deploy your app. The deployment tool you use will pack it up into a `.war` file and send that to the App Engine data centers.

Finally, the output path folder `.../classes` is where the compiled `.java` files that turn into `.class` files for your app are put.

---

I think you should look into some tutorials on IntelliJ and App Engine to make sure that your project was created and configured properly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One you can do that locate build folder in explorer and delete it. After that reopen android studio build it again and run it. Now every thing is fine.